# How to Control appendChild behaviour in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We all know that whenever you appendChild the Child will keep on appending.  My question is how can you control the append child to only append once, twice, three times or any number of specified times.  I'll give an example below, but I'm sure you'll already know what I'm talking about.  A Jquery or Javascript answer is appreciated.  Thanks.

Jquery, but could just as easily be pure javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        $('p:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.id = "newDiv";
        $('#myDiv').append(newDiv);
         newDiv.style.height = "25px";
         newDiv.style.width = "25px";
         newDiv.style.border = "2px solid blue";
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>

    <p>First Paragraph</p>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
    <p>Third Paragraph</p>

    <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="click me" />
</div>
```

Comment: You do realize that this will keep appending divs with the same ID? Also, unless `appendChild` is in a loop, it only runs one. It's not a recursive function or anything.

Comment: Count the number of elements already appended using [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), and use an `if...then` statement to conditionally ignore further appends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to mostly jQuery (smaller). This will limit to 4 divs

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9f353/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        $('p:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        var count = $(".newDiv").length;
        if (count < 4)
        {
            var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr("id", "newDiv" + count).addClass("newDiv").css({ height: "25", width: "25", border: "2px solid blue"}); 
            $('#myDiv').append($newDiv);
        }
    });

});
```

- It uses a `newDiv` class to identify all the items added.
- It uniquely id's each div added with `newDivnn`

The newDiv class is not really needed, so you can just count the `children` under `myDiv`. This one also simply hides the button when it reaches the required limit:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9f353/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myBtn').click(function () {
        $('p:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        var count = $("#myDiv").children().length;
        if (count == 3) {
            $('#myBtn').hide();
        }
        var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr("id", "newDiv" + count).css({
            height: "25",
            width: "25",
            border: "2px solid blue"
        });
        $('#myDiv').append($newDiv);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work.  Interestingly enough, I could never find an answer on the internet to what appears to be a basic question.

Comment: @dragonore maybe *because* it's a basic question. you can't limit what .append does, all you can do is not call .append when you don't want to append, or remove elements before appending more if you don't want more than x to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Give the child you're appending to the `#myDiv` container a unique ID or none at all.
Construct then a for loop to append x number of divs

```
$(function() {
    var xNum = 0;

    $('#myBtn').click(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < xNum; i++) {
            var aDiv = document.createElement("div");
            aDiv.style.height = aDiv.style.width = "25px";
            aDiv.style.border = "2px solid blue";
            $('#myDiv').append(aDiv);
        }
    });

    $('#myField').change(function() {
        xNum = this.val();
    });
});
```

Where #myField could be a slider, input, etc.

Comment: I think they want to "limit" the number of divs created (1 per click), not create them all at once :)

Comment: The question was ambiguous in how they wanted to limit the creation of divs be it by the button click creating more than one or only one, or the button click being limited to how many it can create maximum.

Comment: It was not *that* ambiguous :) "My question is how can you control the append child to only append once, twice, three times or any number of specified times." Not: "append one, two or three"